# OWA Rule for Alias Account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules, outlook-web-access

I get a ton of marketing emails sent to my work email, so I created an alias account with the goal of filtering all email sent to the primary account to some random folder, and all email to the alias into my inbox.

I know I need to set the rule in OWA, otherwise it will only run when I'm logged in to Outlook, but I don't see an option for this. As far as I can tell, OWA doesn't let you set rules based on an alias.

Does anyone smarter than I have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kelvin_D for the input.

This suggestion was exactly what I was trying, however, there was the added issue that once the alias was created, I began receiving email to both my standard account AND the alias. The alias also became my 'primary' email address in the HR system, so all internal emails were being sent to the alias.

I fixed this by modifying the rules a bit to just move anything sent to my old email address to a random folder with the exception of any email that contained the alias email in the header. I think this resolved the issue.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The OWA inbox rule is based on the user mailbox display name. You could set the rule as below:

[image]